# How to open/view .proto file extension

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

I am working on an open-source project(https://github.com/google/science-journal/tree/master/OpenScienceJournal). With this application, I can record an experiment. Recorded experiments are stored with the .proto extension. I tried to compile them to generate classes but failed.

Is there any way to open this kind of files?

Comment: You need the protobuf schema files and the schema compiler; poking around that repository a little, it looks like its Gradle setup should already do what's needed.

Comment: Why my question downvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In protocol-buffers, `.proto` files are *usually* the text-based schema DSL that describes messages, not data; however, it is *possible* that these files do indeed contain the binary data instead (just... unusual). Double-check the files : if they look like:

```
message Foo {
   int32 bar = 1;
   // etc
}
```

then it is the schema; if it is binary-looking, it is probably data.

As to how to read it: the simplest option is to *already have the schema*. If you don't, the data is technically ambiguous - you can probably reverse-engineer it by examining the data, but it can be awkward. You may find tools such as https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode useful for that purpose.

Once you have a schema and the data, you would:

- generate the necessary stubs in your chosen platform from the schema (https://protogen.marcgravell.com/ may be useful here)
- then: use the protbuf library's "deserialize" API for your chosen platform to load the data into an object model
- finally: inspect the object model, now populated with the data

Comment: Any idea on how to process these with Python?

Comment: @Mark put the .proto schema through `protoc` (use use https://protogen.marcgravell.com/), specifying python output; and follow the developer guide for python? https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial